# Current period end value saving as 0 instead of actual value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am trying to save the Stripe's user `current_period_end` to the database. When I create a new subscription the value saves as `0` instead of the actual date their subscription ends.

Is there something I'm missing?

It should be saving as:

```
"current_period_end": 1441292360
```

Subscription.rb:

```
      def save_with_stripe_payment
        customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, plan: plan_id, card: stripe_card_token)
        self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
        self.cancellation_date = customer.subscriptions.first.current_period_end
        save!
      rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
        logger.error "Stripe error while creating customer: #{e.message}"
        errors.add :base, "There was a problem with your credit card."
        false
      end
```

Comment: `@subscription.save_with_payment` but your model has `save_with_stripe_payment`?

Comment: @ChrisBarthol I added code to the model so that part makes sense to you. Check the update. The saving of subscription works fine, it's the current period end that I am having troubles saving to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that this could be an issue with the type of data you're receiving and how you're storing it in your database. Based on the information you have given I would expect you have the wrong field type.

Your code is correct so I would double check to see if your field is a integer.

Answer (score 0):

When Strip creates a new customer it returns the object posted at the bottom of this question.

To access the current_period_end you would need to do `customer.subscriptions.data.first["current_period_end"]`

```
  {
  "object": "customer",
  "created": 1409190039,
  "id": "cus_4fdAW5ftNQow1a",
  "livemode": false,
  "description": "new_paying_customer",
  "email": null,
  "delinquent": false,
  "metadata": {},
  "subscriptions": {
    "object": "list",
    "total_count": 1,
    "has_more": false,
    "url": "/v1/customers/cus_4fdAW5ftNQow1a/subscriptions",
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "sub_4fdAS9IlSOFfiv",
        "plan": {
          "interval": "month",
          "name": "Basic Plan",
          "created": 1409178429,
          "amount": 1200,
          "currency": "usd",
          "id": "basic",
          "object": "plan",
          "livemode": false,
          "interval_count": 1,
          "trial_period_days": null,
          "metadata": {},
          "statement_description": null
        },
        "object": "subscription",
        "start": 1409190039,
        "status": "active",
        "customer": "cus_4fdAW5ftNQow1a",
        "cancel_at_period_end": false,
        "current_period_start": 1409190039,
        "current_period_end": 1411868439,
        "ended_at": null,
        "trial_start": null,
        "trial_end": null,
        "canceled_at": null,
        "quantity": 1,
        "application_fee_percent": null,
        "discount": null,
        "metadata": {}
      }
    ]
  },
  "discount": null,
  "account_balance": 0,
  "currency": "usd",
  "cards": {
    "object": "list",
    "total_count": 1,
    "has_more": false,
    "url": "/v1/customers/cus_4fdAW5ftNQow1a/cards",
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "card_14WHtz4rPA98z9GRTW1QMenU",
        "object": "card",
        "last4": "4242",
        "brand": "Visa",
        "funding": "unknown",
        "exp_month": 1,
        "exp_year": 2015,
        "fingerprint": "0qYXzA0d9EZtsgQ6",
        "customer": "cus_4fdAW5ftNQow1a"
      }
    ]
  },
  "default_card": "card_14WHtz4rPA98z9GRTW1QMenU"
}
```

Comment: The value remains to be `0` in the database for `cancellation_date` unfortunately with your code.

Comment: I would suggest using a debugger and seeing if you are able to see what the customer object looks like and how to separate out the current_preiod_end.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a shot in the dark (because I don't know the format of your `cancellation_date` field or the database you are using), but are you sure you are handling the returned timestamp correctly?

If cancellation_date is a DateTime field, I believe you have to do something like:

```
cpe = customer.subscriptions.first.current_period_end
self.cancellation_date = Time.at(cpe).to_datetime
```

If that isn't the problem then I'd use the console and/or the server output to make sure `current_period_end` is returning what you expect it to when you call `Stripe::Customer.create` (like others have suggested). You really need to determine when the "switch to 0" is happening, so I'd check (in this order):

1. The response from Stripe when you create the customer
2. The value of `customer.subscriptions.first.current_period_end`
3. The value of `self.cancellation_date` after assignment but before saving

There may also be validations or before_save filters that are messing with this field before hitting the database.

That's all my ideas for now :)

Hope this helps!